# MVC 5 Controller Method Consolidation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I am looking to offload some controller functions in my MVC 5 project to a single function.  Both views being passed in inherit from the base view.

```
CompetitionsViewModel:CompRegisterViewModel
```

So far, this appears to work:

```
        private async Task<bool> RegisterUser(RegisterViewModel model, string returnUrl = "")
            {...}
```

Calling code:

```
bool passed = await RegisterUser(model);
```

A few questions on this, though:

1. Is this the proper method of going about this when one of the controllers uses a view that is inherited from another view, and you want a separated function for this?
2. Is there anything I should be concerned about using async in this function?  - Will model errors (ModelState.AddModelError) work as expected within this function?  Everything appears to work on the surface, but I do have a ton of custom JQuery handling extensive error correction prior to this point.
3. Even though this is an async process, will the model still be passed as ref (less of a concern right now, but just for future knowledge).

Basically what is happening here is I have a cart that has the ability to register.  You could also register independently from the cart, so I use a shared view for registration.  As such, both parent views implement the child views, so inheritance of the view model seemed like the most intelligent route.

The options I see on the table are: recreate the process in both controller functions (duplicated code?  ..maintenance nightmare), create an interface (having to update in multiple places when adding a field/changing a field?), or do what I did - one single function that handles both, while the calling methods handle their non-inherited functionality.

Do you see a fourth, better option, or does my solution seem acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is as follows:

1. Still unsure about best practice, but it does work fine.

   - as for whether this is considered good practice or not, I would find it very bad practice to duplicate code, so take it for what it is.
2. It works fine - AddModelError, etc. works.
3. Objects are passed by reference in normal circumstances, so I'm assuming "yes" for now.  Will update if I run into a problem.